# How to send enter key for logIn

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to send Enter key for logIn in MVC, when I have the following `<a id="loginLink" href="#">login</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do recommend not to use a link in the place of a submit button! But if you insist, you can include this jquery that will handle the enter event for you

```
$('body').keyup(function(e) {
   if (0 != $('#loginLink').length && e.which == 13) {
      //document.getElementById('formId').submit()
   }
});
```